# MagicalRecord: How to import values into a related entity

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using a web service which returns results like the following example:

```
{
   "name":"Frank",
   "meals":[
      "cheeseburger",
      "lasagne"
   ]
}
```

My Core Data schema looks like this:

[image: Core Data relationship method]

Using MagicalRecord's `MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject` method, how would I set about mapping the `meals` key to the related `Meals.name` attribute?

I can map the meals manually after, using a `for in` loop, but just wondered if there was a way `MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject` would perform this for me?

Basically I want each object in the JSON "meals" array to become a new Meals entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `importMeals:` on the Person object and do the lookup/create/associate manually.

(longer answer)
every property imported via MagicalRecord calls import(PropertyName) on the target object, by implementing it you can override functionality.